# ASP.NET Repeater Control linking to detailed view via QueryString parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Repeater Control using an XMLDataSource to produce a list of movies (Movies.aspx). I need to link to a detailed page via query parameters like MovieDetails.aspx?movie=Matrix. What control do I use on the MovieDetails.aspx page to render a single movie, preferably using ItemTemplate and my own HTML.

My data source:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="MoviesXmlDataSource" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/Movies.xml" XPath="movies/movie"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

I read the StackOverflow post [Send string with QueryString in Repeater Control in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489517/send-string-with-querystring-in-repeater-control-in-asp-net) and list my items via a repeater like this:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="MoviesXmlDataSource">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="productlist">
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="MovieDetails.aspx?movie=<%#Eval("title")%>"></a>
            <img src="Images/<%#Eval("image") %>" /><br/> 
            <b><%#Eval("title") %></b>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On my MovieDetail.aspx I get the query string parameter as expected. However, I don't know how to fetch this item from my XMLDataSource and render it nicely. I figured out how to do this using GridView and then render a DetailsView depending on what you click in the grid, but it's so ugly. Repeater lets me specify my own HTML, but only for a list and not a single item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out myself. I didn't realize that I could simply access my XMLDataSource from my code behind. I don't *have* to bind it to any control. Here is my solution:

1. Upon PageLoad, get the url parameter *movie*
2. Convert MoviesXMLDataSource to an XmlDocument
3. Fetch the single node where title matches my *movie* parameter
4. Fetch title, description and image link and store as variables
5. In the aspx, render normal HTML and insert <%=title %> and so on...

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      this.movieTitle = Request["movie"];

      string xpath = String.Format("/movies/movie[@title=\"{0}\"]", movieTitle);
      XmlDocument doc = MoviesXmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument();
      XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

      this.title = node.Attributes["title"].Value;
      this.description = node.Attributes["description"].Value;
      this.image = node.Attributes["image"].Value;
   }
   ```

And in the aspx I render stuff as normal:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<asp:XmlDataSource ID="MoviesXmlDataSource" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/Movies.xml" XPath="movies/movie">
</asp:XmlDataSource>    

<h1><%=title %></h1>
<p>
    <img src="<%=image %>"/><br />
    <%=description %>
</p>

</asp:Content>
```

In the end this was really simple. I just got confused by forcing myself to use a control.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the Repeater control is to display a set of data in a consistent manner. And the HTML you apply is actually for a single item in a list of items. And if i were you, i would be using a  [table to display the items](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_repeater.asp). Title in one column, Image in another, details in another etc. Or you could use a

```
Title
--------
Image  |   Description Line 1
       |   Description Line 2
       |   Description Line 3
       |   Description Line 4
--------
```

---

```
Title
--------
Image  |   Description Line 1
       |   Description Line 2
       |   Description Line 3
       |   Description Line 4
--------
```

---

approach.

The only thing that is stopping you from getting a nice list of movies is the knowledge of HTML (which you already know) and creativity! Let your imagination run wild ;)

- Lists
- would
- definitely
- suck
- in
- this
- scenario
- :(

Comment: I understood the purpose of the repeater, and I have a nice list of movies already. My problem is how to render a single movie on a different page. 

How can I fetch a single item from an existing data source, and then render it with pure HTML?