# How to hyperlink list from Access database in C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, hyperlink

My assignment states: Create a site that is similar to Figure 8.9 in ASP.NET 4 Unleashed,   but instead of a list of movie hyperlinks, create a list of your favorite activities (sports, reading, shopping etc.) The image in question is just a simple vertical listing of hyperlinked movies. I am running into issues as it will not build correctly though I have no errors or warnings. I do have a message that states

"Message    1   Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'ConnectionString' is not a valid attribute of element 'AccessDataSource'.  c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Activities\Activities\Activities.aspx  41  5   Activities"

My code is as follows

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Activities.aspx.cs"
Inherits="Activities.Activities" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
    .floater
    {
        float:left;
        border:solid 1px black;
        padding:5px;
        margin:5px;
    }
</style>
    <title>Activities</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <asp:Repeater
    id="Repeater1"
    DataSourceId="srcActivities"
    Runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:HyperLink
    id="HyperLink1"
    Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'
    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Activities.aspx?id={0}") %>'
    runat="server" />

    <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:AccessDataSource
    id="srcActivities"
    ConnectionString="Data Source=.\Access;
    AttachDbFilename=|Desktop|WD364|Activities.accdb;
    Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    SelectCommand="SELECT Id, Type FROM Activities"
    Runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The database is a simple MS Access Table (there is only one) with a few rows and two columns. One the ID and one the Type with the names of the activities. Any help would be greatly apprecitated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <asp:hyperlink id="hlxx" runat="server" 
       NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Activities.aspx?id="+Eval("Type") %>' 
        Target='<%# "_blank" %>'>Eval("Type")</asp:hyperlink>
```

Or see this 
[Send string with QueryString in Repeater Control in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489517/send-string-with-querystring-in-repeater-control-in-asp-net)

and below link have multiple answers

[Link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=hyper%20link%20navigate%20url%20with%20query%20string%20in%20repeater%20site:forums.asp.net&biw=1440&bih=799)

Comment: the above suggestion unfortunately did not work. The error is still there. I did look at the link that you provided but I'm not understanding what I am reading there. The example we are going off of is from our book that has the exact formatting of what I used so I am not understanding why it would throw a message advising that "ConnectionString" is not a valid element for "AccessDataSource".